# Highlight on cell change (perhaps disable lazy loading)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angular-ui-grid

So in a normal table, I have this directive:

```js
app.directive('highlightOnChange', function () {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('highlightOnChange', function (val) {
                element.addClass('flight-item-highlighted');
                setTimeout(function () {
                    element.removeClass('flight-item-highlighted');
                }, 300);                
            });
        }
    };
});
```

this works fine when used like this in an table:

```html
<td highlight-on-change="{{value}}" ng-repeat="(key,value) in items"></td>
```

The idea is to highlight the specific cell once it is updated. This is needed because it is a realtime application, meaning changes will come from the server and needs to be highlighted when changed to let the user know.

But now I am using [Angular UI-Grid](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-grid) which lazy loads the data (which is nice for performance) but not so nice for this feature.

I was able to implement it by defining a cell template:

```html
<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" highlight-on-change="{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}">{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}</div>
```

put it in the options:

```js
$scope.tableColumns = [
    { field: 'name', displayName: 'Firstname', width:100, visible: true, cellClass: self.cellClass, cellTemplate: '/Templates/gridcelltemplate.html' },
    { field: 'gender' }, { field: 'company' }];

$scope.gridOptions = {
    data: self.data,
    columnDefs: self.tableColumns,
    enableColumnResizing: true,
    enableColumnMenus: false,
    rowTemplate: '/Templates/rowtemplate.html',
    headerTemplate : '/Templates/headertemplate.html',
};
```

But the result is that elements are always highlighted on scroll, obviously because they are created at that point (It does work nice for a single update though).

So one solution that I think of would be to change the css class from the controller for a specific column when the data has changed. But because the index will change on scroll for a particular row it would not make any sense. (Because row indexes are always from 0 to x, where x is the last shown row).

Another solution I can do is to keep the same directive, give a function that would call my controller. Controller would somehow need to check if the value is new or not and if so return true. Which would then result in an highlight.

inside directive:

```js
        ....
        scope: {
            changed: '&',
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            attrs.$observe('highlightOnChange', function (val) {
                //now observed value of column, it has changed, call controller to check if it is a new value
                var result = scope.changed({ val: val });
        ....
```

html template:

```html
 <div class="ui-grid-cell-contents" highlight-on-change="{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}" changed="grid.appScope.columnChanged(val)">{{grid.getCellValue(row, col)}}</div>
```

To be honest, I rather have lazy loading disabled, that would solve a lot of problems actually.

*Edit:*

Well, I found by setting `gridOptions.virtualizationThreshold: self.data.length` the lazy loading is disabled. But of course this comes with some major performance issues (having about 20 columns, 1000 rows). So perhaps an more elegant way would be nice :)